# 4x4 post in a 5 gal bucket

Tags: cement

I'm building a lean-to off my 12x20 shop.  I have trees surrounding the building so I can't dig a hole for the 4x4 post.  The header is on the shop at 7 ft and the rafters to extend out 8 ft and attach to 2 4x4 post that are cemented in 5 gal buckets with a 16 in screw anchor going thru the bottom of the buckets.  As the roof is attached to the shop with 2x4 along with the rafters I'm thinking this should hold the lean-too in place. Sound plausible?

Comment: 16" anchor going through the buckets into *what????*

Comment: What are the dimensions of the lean-to roof? Compare the area of that roof to something like a kite-board sail, and the weight of your post & bucket of concrete to that body-weight of a kite-boarder. You really think the wind won't lift it easily?

Comment: Sounds like a death-trap sorry

Comment: Make sure to use plenty of duct tape.

Comment: So you're basically planning to use buckets with concrete as deck blocks?